# Corda enterprise 3.2 fails to load custom configuration file

Tags: corda

We've built a CordApp which connects with RabbitMQ and requires a configuration file to configure the subscribers and publishers to the message queues.

The CorDapp is build against `3.2-corda` but fails to load the configuration file when running on a Corda Enterprise 3.2 node.

The following exception is appended to the logs when we start the Corda web server:

> Starting as webserver: localhost:8080 [ERROR] 11:59:24+0000 [main]
>   messaging.XXX.initializeQueues - Exception caught when subscribing to
>   Rabbit queues [ERROR] 11:59:24+0000 [main]
>   messaging.XXX.initializeQueues -
>   net.corda.nodeapi.internal.config.ConfigUtilities.parseAs(Lcom/typesafe/config/Config;Lkotlin/reflect/KClass;)Ljava/lang/Object;
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   net.corda.nodeapi.internal.config.ConfigUtilities.parseAs(Lcom/typesafe/config/Config;Lkotlin/reflect/KClass;)Ljava/lang/Object;
>   Nov 27, 2018 11:59:25 AM
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime

The code that loads the configuration is as follows:

```
 val connectionConfig = defaultConfig!!
    .resolve()
    .getConfig("app-integration.rabbitMqConnectionConfiguration")
    .parseAs<RabbitMqConnectionConfiguration>()
```

Given we are using a generic `parseAs<RabbitMqConnectionConfiguration>()` method, we assume that this is intended to subsequently call a `parseAs(Config, KClass): Object` method, but for some reason, it seems to be missing?

Comment: But we have sucess with `Corda-3.2-RC02`

Comment: Does this happen when we start the Corda node, or the Corda web-server?

Comment: `Corda-3.2-RC02` is Corda OSS, not Corda Enterprise, so my assumption here is that there is a missing method implementation in Corda Enterprise 3.2 for some reason.

Comment: @series0ne this happens when we start corda web-server

Comment: Are you recompiling the CorDapp against the Corda Enterprise binaries? If not, can you try this and see whether you get an error?

Comment: @Joel how would we specify corda enterprise binaries in gradle?

Comment: See https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-enterprise-V3/build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually take a look at @joel's suggestion above. Corda is not an 'open core' project just yet.

So it's possible that you should compile the cordapps against the enterprise jar to determine whether the issue is the app or a different API between the two corda versions.

My other suspicion is that there might be different versions of java that are being used in the corda OS and the corda enterprise.

I would also see if this issue persists in the latest version of corda as well.